# Checking if code is valid JavaScript without actually evaluating it

Tags: javascript, compilation, eval

Is there a function to test if a snippet is valid JavaScript without actually evaluating it? That is, the equivalent of

```
function validate(code){
    try { eval(code); } 
    catch(err) { return false; }
    return true;
};
```

without side effects.

Comment: Javascript isn't a compiled language.

Comment: the compilation of javascript is too damn high!

Comment: @Bernie sure, edited it for precision.

Comment: @Dokkat, you missed a spot.

Comment: @limelights I'm actually looking for a cross-browser and platform implementation of that feature.

Comment: `new Function(code)` will throw if there's a Syntax Error. Reference Errors cannot be detected without actually executing the code, of course.

Comment: @Dokkat http://www.jslint.com and http://www.jshint.com

Answer (score 16):

Yes, there is.

```
new Function(code);
```

throws a `SyntaxError` if code isn't valid Javascript. ([ECMA-262, edition 5.1, §15.3.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.2.1) guarantees that it will throw an exception if `code` isn't parsable).

**Notice**: this snippet only checks syntax validity. Code can still throw exceptions because of undefined references, for example. It is a way harder to check it: you either should evaluate code (and get all its side effects) or parse code and emulate its execution (that is write a JS virtual machine in JS).

Comment: Good solution. But it doesn't work if the code contains imports

Answer (score 2):

You could use [esprima](http://esprima.org).

> Esprima (esprima.org) is a high performance, standard-compliant ECMAScript parser written in ECMAScript (also popularly known as JavaScript).
>
> Features
>
> - Full support for ECMAScript 5.1 (ECMA-262)
> - Sensible syntax tree format, compatible with Mozilla Parser AST
> - Heavily tested (> 550 unit tests with solid 100% statement coverage)
> - Optional tracking of syntax node location (index-based and line-column)
> - Experimental support for ES6/Harmony (module, class, destructuring, ...)

You can use the [online syntax validator](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html) or install it as [npm package](https://npmjs.org/package/esprima) and run it locally from the command line. There are two commands: `esparse` and `esvalidate`. `esvalidate` yields (given the example from the online syntax validator above):

```
$ esvalidate foo.js 
foo.js:1: Illegal return statement
foo.js:7: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
foo.js:10: Duplicate data property in object literal not allowed in strict mode
foo.js:10: Strict mode code may not include a with statement
```

For the sake of completeness `esparse` produces an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).