# How to check if browser supports Nullish coalescing operator (??)

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check if the browser supports the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
const foo = bar ?? false;
```

I tried this:

- [Checking if code is valid JavaScript without actually evaluating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333269/checking-if-code-is-valid-javascript-without-actually-evaluating-it/15333480)
- `try/catch`

No success. In a browser which doesn't support it the execution of JS stops without any chance to *recover* it.

Comment: what's the problem with `try { eval('null ?? 1') } catch(...)` ?

Comment: @georg What's the problem? I didn't try it. Now I understand. This is a syntax error therefore my approaches didn't work. Thx for your help.

Comment: "*The link does NOT work in this case.*" - please show us the exact code you tried to use. The `new Function` approach from that answer should work just fine. What is the problem?

Comment: @Bergi My mistake, I apologise. The `new Function` approach works and I find it even _more elegant_ than the `eval()` solution.

Comment: Please, may you clarify for me why use `new Function` and not `eval()` approach?

Comment: @AntonioLeonardo I find it more elegant and there are lot of articles in the web why you shouldn't use `eval`. You could add the `new Function()` alternative in your answer and I will then accept it as it covers both possibilities.

Comment: Ok @PeterVARGA, I'm updated the answer with `new Function()`approach, tis was tested too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check if this approach attends you requirement:

```
function coalesceSupport(){
  try{
    const foo = bar ?? false;
    return true;
  }catch{
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

BUT, this block above will trigger compile/interpreter syntax error. Then, to have assertive and correct approach to check if browser support Nullish Coalesce operator, the code follows bellow:

```
function coalesceSupport(){
  try{
    eval("bar = null; foo = bar ?? false;");
    return true;
  }catch(e){
    return false;
  }
}
```

The code tested in Internet Explorer and works fine.

---

**NEW UPDATE:**

After suggestions and read a lot some articles about substituting `eval()` with `new Function()` to create functions dynamically ([but suffers from security and similar - but far less significant - performance issues to eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function)), the aspect of approach is more elegant and obviously more recommended:

```
function coalesceSupport(){
    try{
        new Function("null ?? false;");
        return true;
    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code above was tested in Chrome, Mozilla, Edge and discontinued Internet Explorer too.

Comment: Yeah! You're correctly and I'm agree with your comment, @Ivar. The expression above needs `eval("const foo = bar ?? false;")` to not trigger compiler/interpreter error

Comment: Now I add update on my answer above with correctly approach. Tested in Mozilla, Chrome, Edge and discontinued Internet Explorer and now the can validate if operator is supported by browsers

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing [the comment in "Checking if code is valid JavaScript without actually evaluating it"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15333480/322084) and the comment that [@georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) wrote.

```js
function validate(code) {
  try {
    new Function(code);
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(validate('null ?? false'));
```

Comment: Three `?` - are you sure?

Comment: @PeterVARGA I think it is intentional to show that it doesn't break when using a operator that doesn't exist in the browser. Most of us use browsers that support the nullish coalescing operator, so the function returning `true` doesn't really prove anything.

Comment: @PeterVARGA Yes, that was kind of a mistake. I was testing if I could make it fail with three ? and forgot to remove on ?. I will edit it out.