# How do I catch error coming from a script injected in useEffect in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here Im creating a script tag that i inject after getting a code from an api, so sometimes the code that i get from that api has incorrect syntax but im unable to catch that error, and when i do it either stops the loop from running or stops the whole app.
I want to catch that error and display it afterwards in a state. How Can I achieve that?
PS: the code gets injected to the DOM perfecty when there is no syntax error.

```
useEffect(() => {
    try {
        ArrayEl.forEach((code, index) => {
            try {
                const script = document.createElement('script');
                script.innerHTML = code;
                script.async = true;
                const element = document.getElementById(Ids[index]);
                if (element) {
                    while (element.firstChild) {
                        element.firstChild.remove();
                    }
                    element.appendChild(script);
                } else {
                    throw new Error(`Element with id ${Ids[index]} not found`);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}, [ArrayEl, Ids])
```

Comment: Have you tried checking if `code` is valid syntax with `new Function(code)` as described here, which checks if the code is valid JavaScript and throws an error if the code isn't parseable? See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333269/checking-if-code-is-valid-javascript-without-actually-evaluating-it